# Android:MediaPlayer Support Subtitles with Audio File

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want the subtitles to come when an audio is played on my App (targeted for android version 4.1 or higher ) , how can it be done ?

Comment: Did the solution worked

Comment: i haven't tried it yet !! I will first try it .mp4 format itself and then with .mp3 format

Comment: it will work. I have used in my project. If u want the sample i will give it to you

Comment: it would be great then if it works out for .mp3 also :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this working [example](https://github.com/iTech-Developer/TimedTextTest) it works properly. Its guarantee

Comment: will it also support .mp3 files ?

Comment: it will do it should because it supports .mp4 .webm too. Just give a try. Because this is the only way we can do with android apis. Otherwise u have to use native support